# Not able to deploy war file in weblogic 12c

Tags: java, deployment, ejb, weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm trying to deploy app.war in weblogic 12c. app.war refers an interface(interface_1.class) of lib.war.
lib.war is deployed before app.war and always shows the status as active.

When I target lib.war and app.war in to admin server, I'm able to successfully deploy the app.war.

But when I target lib.war and app.war in to cluster, app.war is not deploying by giving the error message - interface_1.class is not found.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It could be due to the deployment order. When you install the .war files, set the `Deployment Order` for the one you need initialized first to a lower value than the second war. The default is 100.

Comment: I tried with deployment order also but its again the same error... thx